Azure REST API URL for instance pricing of a particular region of a particular OS
I'm trying to figure out get a single JSON entry (count = 1) for fetching the price of an Azure instance at a particular location for an OS.
REST URL for the Azure instance price of Standard_D2s_v3 in eastus, Linux - Pay as you go with just OS in USD :
https://prices.azure.com/api/retail/prices?$filter=serviceName eq 'Virtual Machines' and armRegionName eq 'eastus' and skuName eq 'Standard_D2s_v3' and productName eq 'Virtual Machines Dv3 Series' and priceType eq 'Consumption' and armSkuName eq 'Standard_D2s_v3' and meterName eq 'D2s v3'

But this is returning [] items with count = 0.
Is there an easier means to figure out an instance pricing of a particular region of a particular OS (with or without SQL Server for Windows) ?

Hi @anjanesh, Looks like some issue in your endpoint URL. You can try this URL to fetch price details
https://prices.azure.com/api/retail/prices?$filter=serviceName eq 'Virtual Machines' and armRegionName eq 'eastus' and  armSkuName eq 'Standard_D2s_v3' and meterName eq 'D2s v3' and type eq 'Consumption' and productName eq 'Virtual Machines DSv3 Series' and skuName eq 'D2s v3'

I hope this helps to resolve your issue.

There is an issue with the provided endpoint URL. When I try to run the same URL, I get the same error.

Here is the updated endpoint URL to fetch the price details of Azure VMs.
https://prices.azure.com/api/retail/prices?$filter=serviceName eq 'Virtual Machines' and armRegionName eq 'eastus' and armSkuName eq 'Standard_D2s_v3' and meterName eq 'D2s v3' and type eq 'Consumption' and productName eq 'Virtual Machines DSv3 Series' and skuName eq 'D2s v3'

Output

Here is the endpoint to check if the product name matches Linux.
https://prices.azure.com/api/retail/prices?$filter=serviceName eq 'Virtual Machines' and armRegionName eq 'eastus' and contains(productName, 'Linux')


Below are the supported values for the prices.azure.com API endpoint. You can filter them according to your requirements
{
      "currencyCode": "USD",
      "tierMinimumUnits": 0.0,
      "retailPrice": 0.0688,
      "unitPrice": 0.0688,
      "armRegionName": "eastus",
      "location": "US East",
      "effectiveStartDate": "2023-07-01T00:00:00Z",
      "meterId": "000c494f-505a-508d-84e3-6c512039061f",
      "meterName": "DC8as v5 Low Priority",
      "productId": "DZH318Z09B6C",
      "skuId": "DZH318Z09B6C/000H",
      "productName": "DCasv5-series Linux",
      "skuName": "Standard_DC8as_v5 Low Priority",
      "serviceName": "Virtual Machines",
      "serviceId": "DZH313Z7MMC8",
      "serviceFamily": "Compute",
      "unitOfMeasure": "1 Hour",
      "type": "Consumption",
      "isPrimaryMeterRegion": true,
      "armSkuName": "Standard_DC8as_v5"
    },

